# what is the easy way to exclude folders in /home during backup

Tags: linux, backup, bash

I am doing backup using

```
for a in /home/*
do
//do backup
done
```

I want to exclude some folders in /home . but for loop takes all folders i there.

is there any way so that i can specify exclude list at top which can be used in loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some sort of evaluation in order to check what to exclude from the list of folders you get in the "for"; just using bash this could be (you can use whatever you feel comfortable to evaluate what to exclude (ie sed, grep, awk,...)):

```
exclusiondirs="/home/foo /home/bar" # list of folders to exclude from backup

for a in /home/*; do
if ! [[ "$exclusiondirs" =~ $a ]]; then
    ...do backup...
fi
done
```

However I would have use some other tools for backup such rsync which can exclude by itself, for example:

```
rsync -av /home/* --exclude /home/foo --exclude /home/var destination
```

**Edited**:

Since the bash regex is a bit tricky and difficult to implement in some circumstances I've replaced it with a more robust grep statement:

```
if ! echo "$exclusiondirs" | grep -q "\b$a\b" ; then
```

This grep statement will work in a home dir with names such as (where some dirs share common part names and include spaces within):

```
mkdir -p home/{foo,bar,foobar,a,b,c,a\ b
tree
`-- home
    |-- a
    |-- a b
    |-- b
    |-- bar
    |-- c
    |-- foo
    `-- foobar

~$ echo $exclusiondirs 
/home/foo /home/bar /home/a
~$ for a in /home/*; do if ! echo "$exclusiondirs" | grep -q "\b$a\b" ; then echo $a; fi; done
/home/a b
/home/b
/home/c
/home/foobar
```

Comment: thanks for that , i can use rsync but can i want separate users home dir backups in separate folders in compressed format like `.tar.gz` can i do that in rsync

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Skipping multiple files and folders](http://techtrunch.com/commands/rsync-fast-versatile-remote-local-filecopying-tool) section in this page.